# Cross-database query with memory memory-optimized tables

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

I am trying to tune a system by using memory optimized tables as a cache for frequently used data. The problem is that my system design has separate database (on the same server) siloed by core functionality. I would like to for example have a Curves database that is highly performant in the management of curves. Other databases use the data on this database for valuations etc. What I would like is for the Curves database to have optimized tables that the other database can quickly read, call a function that gets the data or performs some in memory manipulations. Problem is that that I come across this limitation:

> A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables or natively compiled modules cannot access more than one user database or databases model and msdb, and it cannot write to master.

I have tried to work the Microsoft example of creating a memory optimized table type and use that to park the data for use in a destination database, but that did not work - got the same error. I have see examples of copying the data via the tempdb. Both examples require a copy of the data in the destination database, but all I really want to do is read the data and use it in the destination database. Has anyone been able to make this work successfully across databases?

From some testing - they are blisteringly fast so very keen to get them to work. There are a few generic examples on line, but can't seem to find any real world examples of how to make them really useful.